# Creating a if else to display alternative div based on url

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm trying to do an if else statement for displaying one div or the other based on url but it's not working at all only one div constantly displays:

Div 1 is the only one that keeps showing, I've tried numerous work-arounds:

```
    <script>
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("pink") > -1)
    {
    document.getElementById("div2").style.display="none";
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display="none";
    }
    </script>

    <div id= "div2">
    <a id="link2" href="https://example2" target="_top"></a>
    </div>

    <div id= "div1">
    <a id="link1" href="https://example1" target="_top"></a>
    </div>

    <style>
    #link2
{
background: url(http://examplemy.com/wp-content/backtwo.PNG); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
    #link1
    { 
background: url(http://examplemy.com/wp-content/backone.PNG); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
            }
    html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;}
```

I've now put the script at the end but still not working.

Also, take my sites usr as examplemy/pink

Comment: "based on url" -- What is the url and how does "pink" relates to the url?

Comment: what are the 2 URLs that you are testing?

Comment: Since your JavaScript is output before the elements, there could be an issue with your script running before there are elements on the page and so nothing will happen. Maybe try putting your JavaScript inside of document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});

Comment: @AndrewL added the example url added script at the bottom but still not working

Answer (score 0):

The script is running before the divs are loaded. It won't be able to find them; you'll probably see errors in your development console if you open it when loading this page. You should either move the script below the divs, or put the code in an event handler for the load event of the window (`window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... })`) so that it won't run until the divs have loaded. (You can also use the DOMContentLoaded event instead of the plain load event for this case, though that's less well-known.)

Comment: Added the script to the bottom but still doesn't work